# Solving limit given a limit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Given the fact that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1,$$
compute the following limit: 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin(x)}{h}\ $$

How would I go about solving this problem? I have attempted to use trig identities (addition of angles) to try to simplify the problem, but it only seemed to make it worse...

Comment: What did you get when following that idea?

Comment: Try expanding $\sin(x+h)$ using an identity.

Comment: this is simply the derivative of $\sin x$

Comment: @qaphla Um.. Nowhere, really. Or at least it seemed that way to me. I got `(sin(x)cos(h)+sin(h)cos(x) - sin(x))/h` And I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Use the addition formula. Also, note that $cos(h)$ goes to $1$ as $h$ goes to 0.

Comment: @derekorr can you give an example of the addition formula because I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. (That second fact was also in the problem for part b, I assumed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}h &=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{(\sin x \cos h + \cos x \sin h)-\sin x}h & \text{trigonometric sum formula} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin x(\cos h-1) + \cos x \sin h}h &\text{shuffle terms in numerator} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \left(\frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}h + \frac{\cos x \sin h}h \right) & \text{break the fraction} \\
&=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}h +\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\cos x \sin h}h \\
&=\sin x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\cos h-1}h + \cos x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\sin h}h \\
&= \sin x \cdot 0 + \cos x \cdot 1 & \text{apply limit indentities}\\
&= \cos x.  & \text{simplify}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sin(x+h)=\sin x\cos h+\sin h\cos x,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h}=\frac{\sin x\cos h+\sin h\cos x-\sin x}{h}=\cos x+\sin x\frac{\cos h -1}{h} \\= \cos x-\sin x\frac{2\sin^2(h/2)}{h}=\cos x-\sin x \cdot \frac{h}{2} \cdot\left(\frac{\sin(h/2)}{h/2}\right)^2 \to \cos x-\sin x\cdot 0 \cdot 1\\=\cos x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use $\sin(x+h) = \sin(x)\cos(h) + \cos(x)\sin(h)$

Comment: I did, but I don't know what to do after substituting in that identity...

Comment: @StrongJoshua what do you think is $\cos(h)$?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Haven't seen you in a while. Welcome back.

Comment: @GitGud Yes it's been long. I've been busy. It's good to be back. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the difference to product identity $\sin A - \sin B = 2\sin \dfrac{A-B}{2}\cos\dfrac{A+B}{2}$, we get:

$\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{2\sin\frac{h}{2}\cos(x+\frac{h}{2})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sin \frac{h}{2}}{\frac{h}{2}} \cdot \lim_{h \to 0}\cos(x+\tfrac{h}{2}) = $...

Answer (score 0):

This is the limit definition of the derivative for $\sin x$

So,

$$(\sin x)' = \cos x$$

**EDIT**, given any $f(x)$, to find its derivative, through limits we can express it as:

$$\large \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$

Here $f(x) = \sin x$